# Sublime plugin - trailingspaces - not working

Tags: sublimetext2

I installed `trailingspaces` plungin for sublime text 1 week ago. It was working then but stopped working after 2 days. Today, an update for trailing spaces was available. The update fixed the problem on my PC but not on my Laptop.

The only suspicious thing I could find in the setting:

```
    "trailing_spaces_highlight_color" : "invalid",
```

I don't remember what this setting used to be when the plugin was working.

The `delete trailing spaces` option is working but the `highlight` is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try uninstalling the plugin through Package Control, deleting `Packages/User/trailing_spaces.sublime-settings`, restarting ST2, then reinstalling through Package Control. That will reset everything back to its default state, and hopefully get things working again.

The `"trailing_spaces_highlight_color" : "invalid"` entry is correct, as you can see by looking at the [original file on GitHub](https://github.com/SublimeText/TrailingSpaces/blob/master/trailing_spaces.sublime-settings). *`invalid`* is the scope of your theme used to highlight the trailing spaces, in some themes it's pretty obvious - a bright red background with white text, for example, in my [Neon Color Scheme](https://github.com/MattDMo/Neon-sublime-theme) - also available through Package Control, hint hint :). However, some themes don't highlight the `invalid` scope very obviously - some that I looked at only made it a different text color and italicized it, which wouldn't be of any use with spaces. This may be why the plugin apparently stopped working, although I'd still recommend uninstalling and reinstalling it just to get back to baseline.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! It worked. `Packages/User/trailing_spaces.sublime-settings` was the culprit. Just deleting that file solved the issue :)